# inject translator service in my service

Tags: 8, dependency-injection

I am confused by this one.

I want the translator service injected in my service. The closes thing I've found is this one: Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\TranslationManager; ( https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!StringTranslation!TranslationManager.php/class/TranslationManager/8.2.x) but it has no method "t" and it really makes emphasises to not use it's translate function, to use \Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\StringTranslationTrait; instead. But I can't inject this in my service, can I? (how?)

Ultimately, I just want to call t function in my own service.

Answer (score 1):

It looks that there is no need to inject anything. Just use a "use" statement *inside* the class

```
class MyModuleService {
  use \Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\StringTranslationTrait;

  function a() {
    $this->t('should at least not complaint.');
  }
}
```

Comment: You can also extend from ControllerBase and then you get this by default. Note that this falls back to \Drupal::service() in \Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\StringTranslationTrait::getStringTranslation unless you actually do inject that service. So if you want to write unit tests for your class, you might still want to do that.

Comment: @Berdir how would I exactly inject the stringTranslationTrait as a service? Post an answer please

Comment: @Cesc check out the code and answer of this question https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/239239/when-using-the-stringtranslationtrait-in-a-service-why-should-you-inject-the-st It comes down to where the trait gets it's service. Best practices and all that.