# When using the StringTranslationTrait in a service why should you inject the 'string_translation' service aswell?

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I was reading the code comments in the [StringTranslationTrait](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21StringTranslation%21StringTranslationTrait.php/8.3.x) trait and saw the following:

> If the class is capable of injecting services from the container, it
>   should inject the 'string_translation' service and assign it to
>   $this->stringTranslation.

So I created a simple service, used the [StringTranslationTrait](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21StringTranslation%21StringTranslationTrait.php/8.3.x), injected the `string_translation` service and assigned it to `$this->stringTranslation`. I found that when I don't inject the `string_translation` service the `$this->t()` function still works as I expected.

Why should one inject said service into his own service? Is it good practice or are there other benefits such as speed? The comments in the [StringTranslationTrait](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21StringTranslation%21StringTranslationTrait.php/8.3.x) file offer no explanation.

**My service for completeness:**

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\wow\Service;

use Drupal\Core\Url;
use Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\TranslationInterface;
use Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\StringTranslationTrait;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

/**
 * Class RedirectService.
 *
 * @package Drupal\wow\Service
 */
class RedirectService {

  use StringTranslationTrait;

  /**
   * The redirect object.
   *
   * @var \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse
   */
  private $redirectResponse;

  /**
   * RedirectService constructor.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\TranslationInterface $stringTranslation
   *   The string translation service.
   */
  public function __construct(TranslationInterface $stringTranslation) {
    $this->stringTranslation = $stringTranslation;
  }

  /**
   * Sets the redirect.
   *
   * @param string $routeName
   *   Drupal route name to redirect to.
   * @param string $message
   *   Message to show after redirecting. If not provided no message will be
   *   shown.
   * @param string $messageType
   *   Message type of message shown after redirecting.
   */
  public function setRedirect($routeName, $message = NULL, $messageType = 'status') {
    $uri = Url::fromRoute($routeName);

    if ($message) {
      drupal_set_message($this->t($message), $messageType);
    }

    $this->redirectResponse = new RedirectResponse($uri->toString());
  }

  /**
   * Gets the redirect object.
   *
   * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse
   *   The redirect object.
   */
  public function getRedirect() {
    return $this->redirectResponse;
  }

  /**
   * Returns the response object.
   *
   * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
   *   The response object.
   */
  public function send() {
    return $this->redirectResponse->send();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you didn't inject the string translation service into `$this->stringTranslation`, the trait would get it from the static `\Drupal` wrapper

```
  /**
   * Gets the string translation service.
   *
   * @return \Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\TranslationInterface
   *   The string translation service.
   */
  protected function getStringTranslation() {
    if (!$this->stringTranslation) {
      $this->stringTranslation = \Drupal::service('string_translation');
    }

    return $this->stringTranslation;
  }
```

and this should be avoided in OOP code. The main reason for this is to be able to inject mock-up services for code tests.

Comment: Yes and no, the trait also defines a setStringTranslation() method, so even if you don't use constructor injection and at normal runtime, falls back to the container, you could still use that in a unit test. So, recommended, but not strictly necessary.