# Problem with dependency injection (File::load and \Drupal::service)

Tags: 8, forms, files, dependency-injection

In order to make a managed_file field permanent I did this in my module configuration form:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_module\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\ConfigFormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * Class MymoduleSettings.
 */
class MymoduleSettings extends ConfigFormBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getFormId() {
    return 'my_module_settings';
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $config                    = $this->config('my_module.settings');
    $form['my_module_title'] = [
      '#type'          => 'textfield',
      '#title'         => $this->t('Title'),
      '#description'   => $this->t("Enter the title"),
      '#maxlength'     => 64,
      '#size'          => 64,
      '#required'      => TRUE,
      '#default_value' => $config->get('my_module_title'),
    ];
    $form['mymodule_icon']   = [
      '#type'              => 'managed_file',
      '#title'             => $this->t('Icon'),
      '#description'       => $this->t("Upload the image file for the icon"),
      '#upload_location'   => 'public://',
      '#upload_validators' => [
        'file_validate_extensions' => ['gif png jpg jpeg'],
      ],
      '#default_value'     => $config->get('my_module_icon'),
    ];
    return parent::buildForm($form, $form_state);
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    parent::submitForm($form, $form_state);

    $this->config('my_module.settings')
      ->set('my_module_title', $form_state->getValue('my_module_title'))
      ->set('my_module_icon', $form_state->getValue('my_module_icon'))
      ->save();

    // First we just grab the file ID for the icon we uploaded, if any.
    $icon_field = $form_state->getValue('my_module_icon');
    $file_id    = empty($icon_field) ? FALSE : reset($icon_field);

    if (!empty($file_id)) {
      // Make this a permanent file so that cron doesn't delete it later.
      $file         = File::load($file_id);
      $file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
      $file->save();
      $file_usage = \Drupal::service('file.usage');
      $file_usage->add($file, 'my_module', 'file', $file_id);
    }
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function getEditableConfigNames() {
    return [
      'my_module.settings',
    ];
  }

}
```

but I'm getting warning to use dependency injection principle in this case:

```
File::load calls should be avoided in classes, use dependency injection instead
```

and

```
\Drupal calls should be avoided in classes, use dependency injection instead
```

I looked through [Dependency Injection for a Form](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/services-and-dependency-injection/dependency-injection-for-a-form) but still not sure that I really get it.

Can someone explain me what I need to do in this particular case so I can get a better view on this issue and figure it out?

Comment: You should put the "UPDATE" before everything.
Like this, I was reading the issue, and I couldn't find the "File::" call you were complaining about. 
Also, I think it's a good practice to let the "buggy" code stay, so people can make comparisons.

Comment: I believe the OG post only had the submitForm method - I requested to see more so I could see if there were other issues.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are extending [FormBase](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormBase.php/class/FormBase/8.2.x) you can use `create` to inject dependencies. In this case what I think you want is the `entity_type.manager` service and `file.usage`.

```
  /**
   * Class constructor.
   */
  public function __construct(EntityTypeManagerInterface $entity_type_manager, FileUsageInterface $file_usage) {
    $this->entityTypeManager = $entity_type_manager;
    $this->fileUsage = $file_usage;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) {
    return new static(
      $container->get('entity_type.manager'),
      $container->get('file.usage')
    );
  }
```

See this [docs page](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/services-and-dependency-injection/dependency-injection-for-a-form) for more examples.

The `create` method sends arguments to the constructor, and then you set those to instance variables, and voila, there are your dependencies. Be sure to update your file with the necessary `use` statements and declare your protected members (`entityTypeManager` and `fileUsage`) at the top of the form class.

Therefore, you can remove the static ::service call and use:

`$this->fileUsage->add()...`

Also, the reason I am passing entity type manager service, is because you would replace File::load with:

`$this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('file')->load($id)`;

If you need more than that object returns, you may need to use a different service but I don't know that off the top of my head.

Comment: Thank you very much. I changed to this `$file = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('file')->load($file_id);` and another line `$this->fileUsage->add($file, 'my_module', 'file', $file_id);`, but I'm getting `Call to a member function getStorage() on null`

Comment: Have you cleared cache?

Comment: Yes, I did...tried few times...

Comment: Can you update your post with all the form code?

Comment: Yes, I just updated it...

Comment: You must have caught me mid edit - fix your `create` call, it needs to be `entity_type.manager`

Comment: hm, same again...I checked and file is there, also in the database (but status isn't changed from 0 to 1), but I still getting error...

Comment: I figure out that I'm getting the error only on first submit, afterwords file is there and if I save my form again status is changed in permanent without any errors...looks like at the first `$this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('file')->load($file_id)` can't load the file for some reason...any idea?

Comment: Is file id numeric and exist in the database? I'm not really sure.. successive saves won't trigger anything unless another file is uploaded right?

Comment: Yes, it's numeric and it's in the database even I get the error, and if I return on config page and save again everything is ok...

Comment: This looks like a serialization issue. The FormBase has some kind of fallback for services by getting them from `\Drupal` if not set. Subclasses are advised to provide a container factory DI. But the fallback is always there when in some submit requests the service is missing in the unserialized form. And as in the comment from Berdir here it seems to be OK to have this fallback as only injection method when you have a public setter for testing: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/239239/when-using-the-stringtranslationtrait-in-a-service-why-should-you-inject-the-st

Comment: @4k4 thanks, I looked at it, and it's working if I do it as in [your post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/239244/14487), but I'm again get warning when I test the code - `\Drupal calls should be avoided in classes, use dependency injection instead`. Can I do something about that?

Comment: @mixerowsky, the warning is about the correct way. But you have an issue when doing it this way. So either you could try to find out why this is happening or use the work around. As long as you are able to write tests for the form class it should be OK

Comment: @4k4 I fixed it, it's stupid mistake. I declared my `$entityTypeManager` and `$fileUsage` as *private* instead as *protected*...

Comment: @mixerowsky, great this is fixed. This was the first idea which came to my mind, but I didn't dare to ask, because Kevin said in his answer "declare your protected members" ;-)

Comment: @4k4, could you elaborate more about on why we should "declare your protected members", instead of private for example? And how does it relate to the `Call to a member function getStorage() on null`?

Comment: @VladMoyseenko, because private class members can't be serialized and then they are NULL when unserialized.

Comment: @4k4 Ok, but what kind of mechanism used to serialize this protected members? as far as I know php can serialize private members too, am I wrong?

Comment: @VladMoyseenko, Drupal has its own method `DependencySerializationTrait::__sleep`, the php serialization doesn't work because it would serialize all container services, the drupal method only stores the service id.