# How to use t() function in controller?

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I understand Drupal 8 ControllerBase implements StringTranslationTrait so we can use $this->t() in Controller class. 
But I found in Drupal 8 examples code, they setStringTranslation to use t() function. Here is the code.

```
public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) {
    $controller = new static(
      $container->get('database')
    );
    $controller->setStringTranslation($container->get('string_translation'));
    return $controller;
  }
```

The link for their module. https://git.drupalcode.org/project/examples/blob/8.x-1.x/tablesort_example/src/Controller/TableSortExampleController.php

My question is why setStringTranslation when you can just use t() function in the controller.

Comment: Most likely the opinion of using the injected container rather than depending on the `\Drupal` object. It's an opinion. I agree, but I don't agree enough to go out of my way to not use StringTranslationTrait.

Comment: You don't need the setter method to instantiate the object, you can inject via constructor. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/239239/when-using-the-stringtranslationtrait-in-a-service-why-should-you-inject-the-st

Answer (score 0):

`$this->t()` assumes object context. `$this` isn't available in the static context of the create method above.

The ControllerBase provides access to `t()` via a protected function (see below from docs) to it is also not available from the public context. 
`setStringTranslation` however is a publicly available method.

```
StringTranslationTrait::t   protected   function    Translates a string to the current language or to a given language.
...
StringTranslationTrait::setStringTranslation    public  function    Sets the string translation service to use.
```

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Controller%21ControllerBase.php/class/ControllerBase/8.2.x